# Error de memoria en app android al consultar mas de 500 contactos

Tags: java, android-studio

Tengo una app a punto de salir al market pero tengo un problema que no sé cómo solucionar.

> Cuando desde la app hago una consulta de los contactos del teléfono, si el usuario tiene mas de 500 contactos, la app se me queda congelada.

¿Sabéis alguna forma en android estudio, para dar más memoria del teléfono a mi app y así evitar este error?

Hago la consulta de contactos para saber que contactos del teléfono tienen ya mi app y así ponérselos como amigos. De esta forma puede invitarles dentro de la app. Gracias

Os dejo aquí el error

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
>       at es.totdemas.totdemas.Menu$40.onPostExecute(Menu.java:956)
>       at es.totdemas.totdemas.Menu$40.onPostExecute(Menu.java:925)
>       at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
>       at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
>       at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)

Comment: Esto no se debe a la cantidad se debe a que alguno de los elementos que  consultas no tiene una propiedad. Agrega tu código.

Answer (score 0):

No se como haces la consulta en si, pero no es lo mismo un select nombre de 500 que un select * de 500. Creo que no deberías hacer una consulta de 500 de un tiron, no estoy lo suficientemente puesto en android para saber si esta solución es viable pero yo haría las consultas poco a poco. Pongamos como ejemplo una app conocida, el whatsapp. Este no te muestra tus contactos. Te busca o muestra los 10 o 20 primeros y cuando haces scroll y llegas a esos últimos envía una petición de los siguientes y así hasta el infinito.

De esta manera, no solo no se te lagueará la aplicación, si no que será más escalable por que consume menos recursos del servidor al realizar las preguntas y hasta los móviles más antiguos podrán realizar esas consultas y soportar la carga.

Espero haberte ayudado y que me entiendas.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, lo probare y te comento...;))

Comment: Hola @MB_plus Recién intentaste editar la respuesta de jedelwey. En vez de hacer eso, deberías editar tu pregunta agregando cualquier información extra